# Fontspec's LetterSpace disturbing tabbing (luatex only)

Tags: luatex, fontspec, bugs, tabbing

Letterspacing a portion of the text with `fontspec` will "indent" the following tab, but only when compiled with lualatex; xelatex will produce the expected result:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont{Junicode}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
test\qquad\=O ALLCAPS first part\qquad\=second part\\
test\>O {\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=10}ALLCAPS} first part\>second part\\
test\>O {ALLCAPS} first part\>second part\\
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

This looks like a bug -- is there a workaround or even fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is a bug, and I opened a bug report: https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/167

A work around is to add an additional box:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont{Junicode}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
test\qquad\=O ALLCAPS first part\qquad\=second part\\
test\>O {\mbox{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=10}ALLCAPS}} first part\>second part\\
test\>O {ALLCAPS} first part\>second part\\
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

[image]